# How to vertically centre a div inside a vertical scroll parent div? Either CSS or Javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has two divs left side and right side of the parent div.

These two divs should center vertically, but have height auto as it could grow, but if it grows it should adjust its location to continue center vertical.

However the parent div has scroll vertical enable, the divs left and right should ignore any height that is not on the view height.

So if the parent div has a scroll of 2000px height, the left and right should not center vertically in the middle of 1000px, but it should center in the middle of the top of that scroll page if that makes sense.

```css
.overlay_background {
  position: fixed;
  //overflow: hidden;
  overflow: initial;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  //top: 0;
  top: 200px;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay_ws_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 900px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay_background .left_img {
  float: left;
  min-height: 75vh;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.overlay_background .right_img {
  float: right;
  min-height: 75vh;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.overlay_background .text_overlay_container {
  height: auto;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: pre-line
}

.img_size_200 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay_background" id="overlay_background_id">
  <img src="hello" style="width: 40px;cursor: pointer; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 10px;">
  <div class="overlay_ws_container">
    <div class="left_img">
      <img src="" class="img_size_200">
      <img src="" class="img_size_200">
    </div>
    <div class="right_img">
      <img src="" class="img_size_200">
      <img src="" class="img_size_200">
    </div>
    <h1 style="font-size: 30px"></h1>
    <div class="text_overlay_container">

    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn_ws" id="btn_sold_id" style="display: none; cursor: not-allowed">Sold out</button>
    </div>
    Quantity:
    <input id="inp_quantity_id" type="number" class="inp_quantity" value="1">
    <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
      <h1 style="color: inherit; font-weight: bold" id="prices"></h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn_ws" id="btn_ws" style="display: none">Add to basket</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So if the content of the scrollable wrapper is 2000px height you don't want your items to be aligned in the middle (which is 1000px)? But what do you mean by the "middle of the top" ("it should center in the middle of the top of that scroll page if that makes sense.")

The middle of the top is centering horizontally in my opinion?

Comment: I mean the scroll bar starts from top and you can scroll all the way to the bottom, i want to have the div center vertically on top not in the middle of the scrool which would be 1000px

Comment: You mean in the middle of the currently visible area?

Comment: yes that is a easier way to put it. but not fixed.